# Creating a rule to display Terms Of Service upon Ubercart checkout

Tags: ubercart, rules

I have a small web store running Ubercart and with one of the items I must display a terms of service agreement. I have it displayed upon checkout as a requirement to proceed. Some of my other items do not need this service agreement to be purchased.

**Question**: Is it possible to set up a rule to display the Terms Of Service up check when only certain items are in the cart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of failed methods and frustration I found a solution.

You will need the following modules:

- Ubercart Terms of Service (https://drupal.org/project/uc_termsofservice)
- Ubercart Product Checkout Pane (https://drupal.org/project/uc_product_panes)

First install the Terms of Service module and set up your terms accordingly. Then install the Ubercart Product Checkout Pane and set the TOS to appear at checkout with the specified product(s).

This allows you to display the terms for each product that requires them.